# Solving Error on code 'performsFirstActionWithFullSwipe:' In Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

First i am still new in flutter and learning some flutter in open source code.

Recently i am want running some open source project but seem i am have some problem in this code

```
child: SwipeActionCell(
                                                  backgroundColor:
                                                      Colors.transparent,
                                                  key: ObjectKey(
                                                      selectedTransactions[
                                                          int]),
                                                  performsFirstActionWithFullSwipe:
                                                      true,
                                                  trailingActions: <
                                                      SwipeAction>[
                                                    SwipeAction(
                                                        title: getTranslated(context, 'Delete') ?? 'Delete',
                                                        onTap:
                                                            (CompletionHandler
                                                                handler) async {
                                                          Platform.isIOS
                                                              ? iosDialog(
                                                                  context,
                                                                  'Are you sure you want to delete this transaction?',
                                                                  'Delete',
                                                                  () async {
                                                                  DB.delete(
                                                                      selectedTransactions[
                                                                              int]
                                                                          .id!);
                                                                  await handler(
                                                                      true);
                                                                  Provider.of<InputModelList>(
                                                                          context,
                                                                          listen:
                                                                              false)
                                                                      .changeInputModelList();
                                                                  customToast(
                                                                      context,
                                                                      'Transaction has been deleted');
                                                                })
                                                              : androidDialog(
                                                                  context,
                                                                  'Are you sure you want to delete this transaction?',
                                                                  'Delete',
                                                                  () async {
                                                                  DB.delete(
                                                                      selectedTransactions[
                                                                              int]
                                                                          .id!);
                                                                  await handler(
                                                                      true);
                                                                  Provider.of<InputModelList>(
                                                                          context,
                                                                          listen:
                                                                              false)
                                                                      .changeInputModelList();
                                                                  customToast(
                                                                      context,
                                                                      'Transaction has been deleted');
                                                                });
                                                        },
                                                        color: red),
                                                    SwipeAction(
                                                        title: getTranslated(context, 'Add') ?? 'Add',
                                                        onTap:
                                                            (CompletionHandler
                                                                handler) {
                                                          var model =
                                                              selectedTransactions[
                                                                  int];
                                                          model.id = null;
                                                          DB.insert(model);
                                                          Provider.of<InputModelList>(
                                                                  context,
                                                                  listen: false)
                                                              .changeInputModelList();
                                                          customToast(context,
                                                              'Transaction has been updated');
                                                        },
                                                        color: Color.fromRGBO(
                                                            255, 183, 121, 1)),
                                                  ],
                                                  child: Padding(
                                                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                                        left: 15.w,
                                                        right: 15.w,
                                                        top: 7.h),
                                                    child: Row(
                                                      children: [
                                                        Text(
                                                            DateFormat(sharedPrefs
                                                                    .dateFormat)
                                                                .format(DateFormat(
                                                                        'dd/MM/yyyy')
                                                                    .parse(selectedTransactions[
                                                                            int]
                                                                        .date!)),
                                                            style: GoogleFonts
                                                                .aBeeZee(
                                                                    fontSize:
                                                                        17.sp)),
                                                        Spacer(),
                                                        Text(
                                                            '${format(selectedTransactions[int].amount!)} $currency',
                                                            style: GoogleFonts
                                                                .aBeeZee(
                                                                    fontSize:
                                                                        18.5.sp)),
                                                        SizedBox(
                                                          width: 15.w,
                                                        ),
                                                        Icon(
                                                          Icons
                                                              .arrow_forward_ios,
                                                          size: 17.sp,
                                                        )
                                                      ],
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                ),
```

The error is on 'performsFirstActionWithFullSwipe' how to solve it? i am already running flutter upgrade package and using some latest SDK in flutter and still have problem with it, i am already clean flutter too and still having this error

Comment: anyone can answer?

Comment: Plase format your code properly. Currently it's very hard to read, or even to edit by community volunteers who would like to help you.